# Understanding solution of finding nth derivative of $\frac{1}{x^2+px+q}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to understand the solution of the following problem:

Find the nth derivative of $\frac{1}{x^2+px+q}$, where $p^2 - 4q < 0$.

The solution goes in the following manner:

We are using the substitution: $x=t-\frac{p}{2}$. Then we have $x^2+px+q=t^2+\frac{4q-p^2}{4}=t^2+a$, by letting $a=\frac{4q-p^2}{4}$

Now I understand the rest of the problem's solution and the benefit of getting such form of the $x^2+px+q$, but I don't get how the author of the solution came up with such substitution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $$\dfrac{b-a}{(x-a)(x-b)}=\dfrac{(x-a)-(x-b)}{(x-a)(x-b)}=?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider 
$$\frac{1}{x^2+px+q}=\left(x^2+px+q\right)^{-1}=\left(\left(x+\frac{p}{2}\right)^2+q-\frac{p^2}{4}\right)^{-1}=\left(\left(x+\frac{p}{2}\right)^2+\frac{4q-p^2}{4}\right)^{-1}$$

It should be more obvious to you now why that substitution is used. This will allow the power series expansion to be done more easily as well.